# Error C2653: ...is not an existing class

Tags: c++, class

**I keep getting the same error when I definitely created the "non-existent" class** **`RandomNumGuesser`**.

My code:

```
//***************************************************
//Here is the error:
//***************************************************

//error C2653: 'RandomNumGuesser' : is not a class or namespace name

//***************************************************
//Here is my header file
//***************************************************

    #ifndef RANDOMNUMGUESSER_H
    #define RANDOMNUMGUESSER_H

    class Guesser {
          protected:
        int high, low;
        int originalLow, originalHigh;

    public:
        virtual int getCurrentGuess();
        void higher();
        void lower();
        void reset();
    };

    class NumberGuesser : public Guesser {
    protected:
        NumberGuesser();
        NumberGuesser(int l, int h);
    };

    class RandomNumGuesser : public Guesser {
    protected:
        RandomNumGuesser();
        RandomNumGuesser(int l, int h);
    };

    #endif

//**********************************************
//Here is my .cpp file
//**********************************************

    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include "RandomNumGuesser.h"
    #include <time.h>
    #include <cstdlib>

    NumGuesser::NumGuesser(int l, int h){
        low = originalLow = l;
        high = originalHigh = h;
    }

    RandomNumGuesser::RandomNumGuesser(int l, int h){
    low = originalLow = l;
    high = originalHigh = h;
    }

    int RandomNumGuesser::getCurrentGuess(){
        srand(time(0));
        return rand() % high + low;
    }
    void RandomNumGuesser::higher(){
            low = getCurrentGuess() + 1;
    }

    void RandomNumGuesser::lower(){
            high = getCurrentGuess() - 1;
    }

    void RandomNumGuesser::reset(){
            low = originalLow;
            high = originalHigh;
    }
```

I've already made sure to include a `;` after each class's closing `}`

Not sure what else to say.

I could use an experienced eye because I don't see any problem.

Also, i'm using Visual 2013 at the moment. Precompiled headers were included.

Comment: maybe you have more than one version of the header

Comment: *Where* do you get your error?

Comment: You can make your virtual functions to pure virtual functions to override them in the derived subclass.

Answer (score 2):

NumberGuesser != NumGuesser.

You have a syntax error. There are also other problems: `getCurrentGuess` is not part of the `RandomNumGuesser` class (same with the other methods in the `Guesser` class). I believe the error log has been cut in the question.

This is how the cpp should look like

```
#include "RandomNumGuesser.h"
#include <time.h>
#include <cstdlib>

NumberGuesser::NumberGuesser(int l, int h){
  low = originalLow = l;
  high = originalHigh = h;
}

RandomNumGuesser::RandomNumGuesser(int l, int h){
  low = originalLow = l;
  high = originalHigh = h;
}

int Guesser::getCurrentGuess(){
  srand(time(0));
  return rand() % high + low;
}
void Guesser::higher(){
  low = getCurrentGuess() + 1;
}

void Guesser::lower(){
  high = getCurrentGuess() - 1;
}

void Guesser::reset(){
  low = originalLow;
  high = originalHigh;
}
```

Comment: +1 for spotting that. I would guess the alleged error message is for an earlier version of the code. :(

Comment: I believe the error message was due to the constructor function which didn't exist. The log might have been cut

Comment: I thought that if I made the member functions of the Guesser class public to the other classes, I could use them as well as the private variables(though not directly). Could you clarify the correct use of : public... for me?

Comment: Sure: you need to define the functions for the class where they're declared (exception for the pure virtual ones, but I'm not bringing them here). The "public" keyword inside a class controls how those methods and variables are visible on the outside for someone that has an object of that class. The "class Name : public Otherclass" keyword instead controls how functions and members of the base class are inherited for the derived class. You should read more about these concepts (http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Classes/Inheritance and any good C++ book)

Answer (score 1):

The `RandomNumGuess` doesn't have the member functions

```
int getCurrentGuess();
void higher();
void lower();
void reset();
```

Yet you define them in the source file.

Are they supposed to be abstract virtual functions perhaps?

You're also missing to define the default constructor for both `NumberGuesser` and `RandomNumGuesser`.